# Why is there an acute accent from some conjugations of "mener" in present tense indicative?

Tags: diacritiques

The Collins diction provides present tense indicative conjugation of "mener".  All conjugations have an acute accent above the 1st "e", except for "nous" and "vous".  If I listen to the [online pronunciation](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french-verb-mener.html), the first syllable sounds the same for all conjugations.  Why is there an acute accent from some of these conjugations?

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/mener

Comment: It would help if you gave a direct quotation of the "*All conjugations have …*" text.  In particular, it would make it a lot more obvious to readers that it's really a grave accent that's in question, not an acute accent.

Comment: I linked to the Reverso conjugation.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first syllable of the first and second person plural **do not** sound the same as other conjugations:

| Conj. | IPA |
| --- | --- |
| *je m**è**ne* | /mɛn/ |
| *tu m**è**nes* | /mɛn/ |
| *il/elle/on m**è**ne* | /mɛn/ |
| *nous m**e**nons* | /m**ə**nɔ̃/ |
| *vous m**e**nez* | /m**ə**ne/ |
| *ils/elles m**è**nent* | /mɛn/ |

As you can see, all forms are pronounced the same (/m**ɛ**n/) except *m**e**nons* and *m**e**nez*.

Comment: OK, thanks, jilliagre.  It's probably must my poor ability to discern between the [online pronunciation](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french-verb-mener.html).